# Is the boundary of the unit sphere in every normed vector space compact?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

I wanted to ask whether the boundary of the unit sphere in every normed vector space is compact?

I know that this is true for simple examples, but how is it in general?

Comment: This is true exactly if the normed space $X$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: is this easy to see why?

Comment: IIRC the so called "Riesz lemma" tells you that given $X$, $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and a subspace $U$ then there is $x \in X$ with $\lvert x\rvert = 1$ and ${\rm dist}(x,U) \ge 1 - \epsilon$. Use induction to construct $(x_n)$ such that $\lvert x_n - x_m \rvert \ge \frac 12$ for any $n \ne m$.

Comment: Thank you...didn't know this. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Take
$$
\ell^2 = \{(x_n) \in \mathbb{R} : \sum |x_n|^2 < \infty\}
$$
with the norm
$$
\|(x_n)\| = \sqrt{\sum |x_n|^2}
$$
And consider the vectors
$$
e_n = (0,0,\ldots, 0, 1,0,\ldots )
$$
with $1$ in the $n^{th}$ spot and $0$ elsewhere.

The sequence $\{e_n\}$ is contained in the unit sphere, and has no convergent subsequence.

In general, the unit sphere is compact iff the space is finite dimensional. One way to prove this fact uses the [Riesz' Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma)

Answer (score 2):

One can prove quite generally that a (Hausdorff) topological vector space $E$ over the real numbers is locally compact if and only if $E$ is finite-dimensional. This means in particular that the unit ball in any normed vector space $E$ isn't compact if $E$ is infinite-dimensional. It follows that the unit sphere in such $E$ cannot be compact either; if it were, then so would be the unit ball which is a topological cone on the unit sphere.

Terence Tao has a nice write-up of this general result (originally due to Weil) [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/).

Remark: the Hausdorff condition is very weak; for TVS it is equivalent to saying that any two $x, y$ have the same neighborhoods only if $x=y$.