# In a normed space $X$ with field $\mathbb{R}$, is $\{ x \in X \mid \|x\| =1\}$ compact in general?

Tags: real-analysis

In a normed space $X$ with field $\mathbb{R}$, is $\{ x \in X \mid \|x\| =1\}$ compact in general?

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ yes but for completely general one, not sure if it's true.

If yes in general, is there any simple proof for it?

Comment: Seems duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/494451/4280

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a normed space $X$, $\{x \in X: \|x\| = 1 \}$ is compact (in the norm topology) iff $X$ is finite-dimensional, so essentially homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.